# How can I use local cache and only update changed documents using Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a calendar app and I'm currently fetching the data from firestore to populate the calendar. Eventually, there will be a lot of data to be fetched and I'm trying to understand the caching system of Firestore but can't get behind it.
What I ideally want to achieve:

Always use cached data and only update those documents, which are new, edited or deleted.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Whenever you add an observer to a Firestore collection, you're presented initial data for that collection. That's enables you to populate your UI with fresh data. Then, Firestore will present changed data (added, changed or removed) so you can live update your UI. No need to use or cache data

Comment: I actually want to use the cache in order to prevent huge amounts of reads, since sometime in the future I will end up with quite some data. I'm currently using onSnapshot,, which works perfectly fine, but its the amount of reads at some point that I'm worrying about.

Comment: You could add a query to your listener function. When data is read, store the timestamp of when that happened. The next time the data is read, only add a listener to data *after* that timestamp. Then you will only be looking at "new" data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force the SDK to read from the cache, you can [specify source options when calling `get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options).

If you find yourself doing this everywhere though, it might make sense to consider using another database than Firestore as that is primarily an online, cloud-hosted database that continues to work while you're temporary offline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually want to read from cache for one part of the app (calendar part) since at some point there will be alot of data. To save read costs I would like to load from cache and only update the documents that are actually edited, added or deleted. I'm guessing that other calendar apps have the same approach.

Comment: It isn't quite answered yet. I know I can use "get()" and specify the source, but when doing so it won't update any changed documents. In my case, I'm wondering if I could combine "get()" with source "cache" and a listener to update any changes, new documents or deleted documents. When I open up a calendar app, for example google calendar, I can see all my data immediately and a loading icon and after loading changes will be visible. I don't want to fetch all the data every time, the app is opened.

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+only+new+data?

Comment: Hey @CrypticalMindz Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Hey @Frank, I haven't really. I'm going to beta test the app very soon and will see, how fetching data will behave. According to different documents, fetched data will persist automatically when using firebase. The known onSnapshot will then check for just updated data. I can't confirm if that is the case. I will find out soon and will let you know! Thanks for asking.

Comment: Hey @Frank, after I took a step back to rethink this project, I accomplished what I wanted to do by stepping away from expo and using realm.io and firebase in combination. Every document in Firebase now has a timestamp and when the user opens the app, it will only fetch documents, that are newer than the last time the user opened the app. Key for me was, that I could basically copy the firebase document structure over to realm.